# On Ionic 2, XMLHttpRequest cannot load .. with Laravel api

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic2

This is my scenario:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://phi.dev/api/login. Redirect from 'http://phi.dev/api/login' to 'http://localhost:8100/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.
```

I have a Aungular2/Ionic 2 App on local and a Laravel Web API for authenticating user.
if I call this Web API from my Angular2 Module, I get an exception as given above.

Note: In Chrome Network, I could my angular service is being called 2 times. First with Request Method: OPTIONS and second time with Request Method: Get, which returns Http 302.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the request is external and because you are serving the application locally you will have CORS issues.

To avoid such issues **locally** (when using `ionic serve`), you have to setup a local proxy in the ionic configuration files.

Check your Ionic 2 project directory and locate the file `ionic.config.json`: it usually is in the root directory of the project (and need to be there, along with package.json and so on).

Open the file, and add this (do not forget to be SURE that the line BEFORE that one ends with a comma (`,`), since it's a json file):

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/server",
      "proxyUrl": "http://phi.dev"
    }
  ]
```

Now, in the section where are you are performing the HTTP request, replace the `http://phi.dev` with `/server`. I will give you an example here.

I do recommend you, however, to be aware that **such edit will make your compiled app to NOT work, so you likely want to put a debug flag for testing and compiled environments, like this:**

```
class MyServiceOrComponent {
   private debug: boolean = true; // Set this flag to FALSE when you need to actually compile the app for any real device.
   private server: string = this.debug ? "/server" : "http://phi.dev";

   constructor(private http: HTTP) {
      const login = "/api/login"; // don't to it exactly like that, make a static list or something like this to store paths.
      let request = this.http.get(this.server + login).then((res) => {
         console.log(res);
      });
   }
}
```

What happens, explained briefly, is that if you perform the HTTP request as "localhost" it will throw you an exception (because of the CORS policy). Such will happen only when you are running the application in your testing environment (localhost). To avoid such, you provide a proxy, so that the request will be valid.

Comment: Thank a lot !! It works now. Thank for all explanations !

Comment: you're welcome, remember to set the flag to false when you need to compile. Also, as a further issue, remember that if you run **ionic build** and you forget about the flag and leave it to true, you also will need to edit more code when you build again, because if you do a build again after changing the debug flag it may not reflect the changes on the compiled APK, so be aware of that as well ;) the cleverest you can do, in such a case, is to commit some changes on any server (which will trigger the daemon to recompile everything!)